# KeyStore Explorer - Created key pair?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore, keytool

I've been working with certificates, symmetric and asymmetric keys, and things related to web application security. I am developing a web application in Tomcat 7, and I must perform a secure exchange of data between client and server using TLS. In my research, I found the [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/) (V. 5.1).

I have some questions related to the use of this program. I know that here may not be the appropriate place to make these types of questions, because the site owner of KeyStore Explorer has a [forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/keystore-explorer/discussion/general/). However, the forum does not allow me to create new topics.

---

When we create a new key pair, we face a window which asks us to choose the algorithm used for the pair generation. After choosing, key generation is made, and then a new window is displayed to the user with the strange name "Generate Key Pair Certificate":

[image]

It is on this screen that comes some doubts. In this new screen, the program request the user to choose a signature algorithm, a validity period, and the name, where data from user entity's key pair must be filled.

What does it mean? Am I creating a Digital Certificate signed by myself? And if I am, is there a way to create only a key pair? I was not supposed to create a pair, and from that create a CSR to send it to a Certificate Authority with CSR containing (**then**) the details of the entity requesting the digital certificate (in case, me)?

With the [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html), I believe we can create a key pair only. But the funny thing is that when we create a keystore with a key pair with the keytool, we open the generated file with the KeyStore Explorer and the pair seems to have been signed by the creator himself, as a digital certificate, for instance:

[image]

(Note that we have two fields, "subject" and "Issuer"...)

What I really want is to be able to create a key pair and from that pair generated I want to create a CSR. I know in the program itself comes with documentation. I researched and read the part named "Key Pairs" (the "Generate Key Pair" topic and etc.), but unfortunately I could not solve this confusion. Would someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong and what this all mean?

As always, I thank you all for your attention and time.

bibliography:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-keytool-essentials-working-with-java-keystores

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

http://ruchirawageesha.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/how-to-create-clientserver-keystores.html

http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/releases.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described on the following web page, key pairs can only exist in a Java key store together with at least one certificate. That is why KeyStore Explorer (and keytool as well) always generate a self-signed certificate for a new key pair:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

After you have created the new key pair, simply right-click on the entry and select "Generate CSR".

After the CA has signed a certificate for the CSR, right-click on the key pair again and select "Import CA reply". The self-signed certificate is then replaced by the one from the CA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really! It makes sense what you said, and according to the documentation, this seems to be really like that. I apologize for doing this kind of question here, but I do not use and do not know the sourceforge to nothing but downloading files. Anyway, thanks again.